# Calculating the average distance between infinite random point pairs within a polygon

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry

I need to come up with a mean figure for the distance between any two points within an irregular polygon. Is there a name for what I'm looking for? All distances would be as-the-crow-flies.

Thanks very much

**Example**

Take any country (with realistically complex borders), and assume people were spread evenly across the territory. Half the people are then given a random 'buddy' somewhere in the country they have to travel to (as the crow flies). What is the average distance that would need to be travelled?

**Actual use case**

I'm calculating travel times for commuters, based on calculated travel times between neighbourhoods of a city (which take the form of irregular and irregularly-sized polygons). However, some people travel to a workplace that's in their own neighbourhood. For these people, the calculation returns 0 travel time. I need to come up with a decent estimate of distance travelled (which I'll use to estimate travel time) for these people, one which takes into account the odd sizes and shapes of their different neighbourhood polygons.

Comment: I don't know of a name for that statistic. I think it is hard to calculate, perhaps particularly hard if the region is not convex. If you [edit] the question to tell is why you need this information we might be able to help.

Comment: Simulation would get you an answer quickly enough (put a bounding rectangle around your polygon and use rejection sampling to get a set of points and then average all the distances between pairs).  You could even take account of the curvature of the earth

Comment: It turns out it's significantly easier to compute the mean *squared* distance between two points, since in that case you end up with a (rather involved) polynomial expression in the coordinates of the vertices.

Comment: @EthanBolker thanks for your comment, I've just added the reason why I need this info

Comment: @Kajelad Would that work for the "actual use case" as described in the now-edited original post? Could I just square root them to get the actual distances?

Comment: @Henry there's 553 polygons so I'm trying to avoid that, but yeah it wouldn't be impossible. Would be nice if there was an elegant solution though!

Comment: @Ben You could apply it to the your use case, but the result would be different. The so-called "root mean square" distance is different from the mean distance (e.g. it weights longer distances more heavily) but it is more useful in some applications. Depending on the data you have, a more empirical approach might be best (e.g. seeing if mean travel time tends to scale with area/diameter/variance/etc. in a predictive way).

Comment: @Kajelad in that case I think I'm probably better off with Henry's solution of just generating random points and calculating the random area. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: For your actual use case consider using  something like half the diameter of a neighborhood for commuting in that neighborhood. Even a commute to next door won't be near $0$ since a real commute would count the time to put on one's coat and lock the door and chat with a neighbor on the way down the walk. For the time between neighborhoods use the distance between their centers of gravity. (That will make some short trips across borders too long, but I can't imagine that causing a problem in your application.)